# GIS Query improvement

Tags: postgis-2.2

Could someone suggest on the below query?

One of the queries which was created on GIS data is taking a long time and even it is not taking the index as well. I have included all the required details for reference.

## Database Stack:

PostgreSQL : 9.5.15
Postgis: 2.2.7

## Table Structure:

```
ALTER TABLE SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME ADD COLUMN parental_path text;
```

## Created Indexes on column parental_path:

```
CREATE INDEX cable_pair_parental_path_idx
  ON SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME
  USING btree
  (md5(parental_path) COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
 
CREATE INDEX cable_pair_parental_path_idx_fulltext
  ON SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME
  USING gist
  (parental_path COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

## Sample data in "parental_path" column:

```
'route--2309421/2951584/3373649/2511322/1915187/2696397/2623291/2420708/2144348/2294454,circuit--88458/88460,sheath--8874'
```

## Actual Query:

```
SELECT seq_no + 1 FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME WHERE (parental_path LIKE '%,sheath--' || cable_seq_id || ',%' OR parental_path LIKE 'sheath--' || cable_seq_id || ',%' OR parental_path LIKE '%,sheath--' || cable_seq_id OR parental_path = 'sheath--' || cable_seq_id) ORDER BY seq_no DESC LIMIT 1;
```

## Explain Plan:

```
Limit  (cost=108111.60..108111.61 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=4597.605..4597.605 rows=0 loops=1)
 Output: ((seq_no + 1)), seq_no
 Buffers: shared hit=2967 read=69606 dirtied=1
 ->  Sort  (cost=108111.60..108113.09 rows=595 width=4) (actual time=4597.603..4597.603 rows=0 loops=1)
       Output: ((seq_no + 1)), seq_no
       Sort Key: TABLE_NAME.seq_no DESC
       Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
       Buffers: shared hit=2967 read=69606 dirtied=1
       ->  Seq Scan on SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME  (cost=0.00..108108.63 rows=595 width=4) (actual time=4597.595..4597.595 rows=0 loops=1)
             Output: (seq_no + 1), seq_no
             Filter: ((TABLE_NAME.parental_path ~~ '%,sheath--64690,%'::text) OR (TABLE_NAME.parental_path ~~ 'sheath--64690,%'::text) OR (TABLE_NAME.parental_path ~~ '%,sheath--64690'::text) OR (TABLE_NAME.parental_path = 'sheath--64690'::text))
             Rows Removed by Filter: 1930188
             Buffers: shared hit=2967 read=69606 dirtied=1
```

I have created indexes as per suggestion of @JGH. Somehow I am getting below issues.

CREATE INDEX ON myTable (parental_path text_pattern_ops);
ERROR: index row size 2960 exceeds maximum 2712 for index "bundle_parental_path_text_idx_gin1" HINT: Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed. Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing. ********** Error **********

ERROR: index row size 2960 exceeds maximum 2712 for index "bundle_parental_path_text_idx_gin1" SQL state: 54000 Hint: Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed. Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing.

CREATE INDEX ON myTable USING gin (parental_path gin_trgm_ops); ==> Created as per instructions.

CREATE INDEX ON myTable (parental_path);
ERROR: index row size 2960 exceeds maximum 2712 for index "bundle_parental_path_trgm_idx_gin" HINT: Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed. Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing. ********** Error **********

ERROR: index row size 2960 exceeds maximum 2712 for index "bundle_parental_path_trgm_idx_gin" SQL state: 54000 Hint: Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed. Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing.

Even after creating the gin index as per 2nd instruction, taking the same time.

Answer (score 5):

`like` queries needs special indexes.

1) if the wildcard char `%` is at the beginning of the string, use

```
CREATE INDEX ON myTable (parental_path text_pattern_ops);
```

2) if the wildcard char `%` is at the end of the string, use

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE INDEX ON myTable USING gin (parental_path gin_trgm_ops);
```

And let's not forget that these indexes are not suitable for equality, so you also need a 3rd index, a regular btree

```
 CREATE INDEX ON myTable (parental_path);
```

You can read more in this [article](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2016/08/pgsql-text-pattern-ops.html) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54173068/slow-varchar-index-performance-in-postgres).